# New line breaks custom markdown extension

Tags: regex, python-2.7, markdown, line-breaks

I'm writing an extension for python-markdown, that is supposed to put the text inside some custom tags of mine into a styled div.

I have created a simple Inline Pattern class that encapsulates matched expression in a div tag. My regex is as follows: `r'(\{mytag_start\})(.+)(\{mytag_end\})'` which then is put inside `"^(.*?)` --- `(.*?)$"` by the markdown.inlinepatterns.Pattern class upon compilation, so that the compile method is called as `re.compile("^(.*?)%s(.*?)$" %r'(\{mytag_start\})(.+)(\{mytag_end\})')`.

At a first glance this does seem to do the trick, however I've noticed that all line breaks need to be hardcoded as `<br>` tags.

So

```
{mytag_start}This code<br>
will work{mytag_end}
```

However, the following code breaks the entire markdown

```
{mytag_start}This code

will not{mytag_end}
```

So instead I just get the entire above block unprocessed in plain text.

I tried supplying re.MULTILINE and re.DOTALL to the `re.compile` but it didn't help. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** [Here](http://pastie.org/4897552) is a sample extension file that exhibits the aforementioned problems. I then load the extension in my django template using `{{ content:"mdx_MyExtension"}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a non-greedy operator (`+`immediately followed by `?`) :

```
r'(\{mytag_start\})(.+?)(\{mytag_end\})'
```

**Full regex :**

`^(?:.*?)(\{mytag_start\})(.+?)(\{mytag_end\})(?:.*?)$`

**Flags :**

DOTALL, IGNORECASE, MULTILINE

**Data test** :

```
blah 
blash
<h1>Title</h1>
{mytag_start}This code<br>
will work{mytag_end}
<b>bold</b>

{mytag_start}This code

will not{mytag_end}
```

**Output :**

```
# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[(u'{mytag_start}', u'This code<br>\nwill work', u'{mytag_end}'), (u'{mytag_start}', u'This code\n\nwill not', u'{mytag_end}')]
```

Comment: Add MULTILINE flag. Additionnaly, I have added non capturing groups to have less data when calling `findall` (See **Full regex**).

Comment: Tried all of above, except for the starting/ending `(?:.*?)` tags. Using those crashes the entire server (page won't load and server becomes unresponsive). There must be something else, markdown specific that causes this.

Comment: Did you try the regex alone ? `/(\{mytag_start\})(.+?)(\{mytag_end\})/IGNORECASE,MULTILINE,DOTALL`

Comment: I did, and so did you. So again, there must be some markdown-specific issue I cant put my finger on..

Comment: Change line 12 from `self.compiled_re = re.compile("^(.*?)%s(.*?)$" % pattern, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)` to `self.compiled_re = re.compile("%s" % pattern, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: Nope, nothing. The problem remains.

Comment: Can you post on pastie.org the actual html code parsed by the regex ?